# CSS - using css object instead of background-image

Tags: css

I have a button class styled in css, in which background image is used, like this:

```
.button {
  display: block;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 30px 28px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('foo.png');
}
```

The shape in .png is really simple - it's just an orange circle. So I want to draw it in css instead, to avoid using external asset. So I thought of using the following css object (which draws an orange circle):

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Is there some way to use that in such a way, that it would behave exactly as the `background-image` .png? (I know I could just make another button class in which I would have drawn the button differently but I want to reuse the button class already available).

Comment: You basically have to have a div behind the div which needs the background, with the new innerdiv having another div inside with CSS similar to: `width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 25%;`

Comment: div-ception... I know :) but I'm more of a web developer, than a web designer, so I won't post it as a solution... There are probably better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using SVG in a data URI? Here's a [fiddle showing the example](http://jsfiddle.net/5t803qx2/) and the code used to generate it (the link is just 194 characters long):

```
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="28">'
        + '<ellipse cx="15" cy="14" rx="15" ry="14" fill="orange"/></svg>';
location.href = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg);
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know something like that is even possible, great tip!

Comment: Note that for IE support, [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) requires 9+ to work just like [`border-radius`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) does.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using a pseudo element, I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6etpee5/1/). You can play with the dimensions of course.

```
.button {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;

    /* just to show where the button is */
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.button:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    /* make sure background is behind text */
    z-index: -1;

    /* center circle in button, negative margins = half of circle dimensions */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;

}
```